# Audio ended event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, audio

Have some trouble with catch this event. 
Have:

```
<div id="click_me"></div>    
<audio class="fo_audio">
       <source src="track1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg; codecs='mp3'">
    </audio>
    <audio class="fo_audio">
       <source src="track2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg; codecs='mp3'">
    </audio>
    <audio class="fo_audio">
       <source src="track3t.mp3" type="audio/mpeg; codecs='mp3'">
    </audio>
```

and try to do smth:

```
song_number = 0;
$("#click_me").click(function(){
$("audio").get(song_number).play()
    });     
$("audio").get(song_number).ended(function(){
    song_number++;
    $("audio").get(song_number).play();
    });
```

How to do it work?

Comment: alestanis, I want to play songs one by one. So, I need to catch 'ended' event for that, but I can't and ask you to help me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only assigning an `ended()` handler to the first audio clip.  Try this:

```
var count = $("audio").size();
$("audio").each(function (song_number) {
  if (song_number < count-1) {
    this.ended(function () {
      $("audio")[song_number+1].play();
    });
  }
});
```

This is untested.  It loops over each audio clip, and attaches an `ended()` event that will start playing the next clip.  The last clip does not get an event handler.

Comment: Thank you dude! That help with some remarks:
var count = $("audio").length;
$("audio").each(function (song_number) {
  if (song_number < count-1) {
    this.addEventListener("ended", function () {
      $("audio")[song_number+1].play();
    });
  }
});

Comment: what if my audio files were dynamically generated from javascript audio object?, how do i use this?

Comment: var currentSong = 0;
$('#playall').click(function () {
     audio.play();
     showDuration()
     currentSong = $('#playlist li').index()
});

audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    currentSong++;
    if (currentSong == $('#playlist li').length) {
        currentSong = 0;
    }
    var nextsong = $($("#playlist li")[currentSong])
    initAudio(nextsong)
    audio.play();
    
    showDuration()
})
In my case, the audio object is dynamically created , how do i still implement this?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around for a bit I ended up with this :

HTML:

```
<audio class="fo_audio" controls="controls">
   <source src="http://cache.gizmodo.com/assets/resources/mp3/Woman64.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   <source src="http://cache.gizmodo.com/assets/resources/mp3/WomanWAV.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
<audio class="fo_audio" controls="controls">
   <source src="http://cache.gizmodo.com/assets/resources/mp3/FeelGood64.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   <source src="http://cache.gizmodo.com/assets/resources/mp3/FeelGoodWAV.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
<audio class="fo_audio" controls="controls">
   <source src="http://cache.gizmodo.com/assets/resources/mp3/Carmen64.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   <source src="http://cache.gizmodo.com/assets/resources/mp3/CarmenWAV.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
<div>
<button class="play" data-which="0">Play 0</button>
<button class="play" data-which="1">Play 1</button>
<button class="play" data-which="2">Play 2</button>
<button class="play" data-which="all">Play all</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var playing = false;
function playCascade(e) {
    if(playing) { return; }
    var song_number = e.song_number || 0;
    var $a = $("audio").eq(song_number);
    if($a.length) {
        $a.get(0).play();
        $a.off('ended').on('ended', function(){
            playing = false;
            if(e.continu) {
                playCascade($.extend(e, {
                    'song_number': song_number + 1
                }));
            }
        });
        playing = true;
    }
    else {
        playing = false;
    }
}
$(".play").on('click', function(e) {
    var which = $(this).data('which');
    playCascade($.extend(e, {
        'song_number': Number($(this).data('which')) || 0,
        'continu': which == 'all'
    }));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bbPCk/2/)**

Notes:

- Play sequence is achieved with recursion.
- Event object `e` is extended to pass custom data.
- A new 'ended' handler is attached to the audio objects at each play.
- 'continue' is a javascript reserved word, therefore best avoided. Hence 'continu'.
- The demo has an extra line which causes just the last 5 seconds of each clip to be played.
- To hide the audio elements, remove `controls="controls"` from the `<audio>` tags.
- Tested in Opera 12.02 .

And here's a variant of the code : http://jsfiddle.net/bbPCk/3/

Comment: Thank you for the answer man! But why so overloaded code? More simple way exists for this task, please see the answer.

Comment: Yes, for sure my code may seem a bit long but it does a whole lot more than the answer you have accepted, which is fine if all you want to do is play all three tracks in cascade. My solution offers the flexibility to play each track individually or all tracks in cascade. It also includes an inhibition to prevent two commanding tracks to play simultaneously. So, in my opinion, the answer you accepted is only a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

```
var count = $("audio").length;
$("audio").each(function (song_number) {
  if (song_number < count-1) {
    this.addEventListener("ended", function () {
      $("audio")[song_number+1].play();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also believed that the event "ended" worked badly. It was an edge effect (considering my context) of not using the removeEventListener.
So, be aware : if you remove an AudioElement, do not forget to remove the concerned installed event handlers, too.